# Xerces-C failing while putting colon in root name

Tags: c++, xml, soap, xerces-c

I am trying to create a soap WSDL via xerces in C++. I just want to create XML and put it in one file.

While creating xml I am using below code snippet to create xml document

```
pDomDocument = p_DOMImplementation->createDocument("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
                               convertStringToXmlCh("soapenv:Envelope"),
                               0);
```

But this line is throwing exception while running .Exception is : "Caught dom exception with message :invalid or illegal XML character".

Also my xml has three namespace apart from default namespace. How can I add this via xerces.

But the time I remove colon(:) from root name in createDocument function the flow run. Can you please let me with how can I put namespace name in xml document via xerces.

I tried searching a lot on google without success.

Edit 1:

```
    DOMImplementation* p_DOMImplementation = NULL;
        p_DOMImplementation = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(XMLString::transcode("core"));
        DOMDocument* pDomDocument=NULL;

        try
        {
            pDomDocument = p_DOMImplementation->createDocument(convertStringToXmlCh(uri),  //Root element namespace URI
                                                        convertStringToXmlCh(rootNode), // Root element name
                                                         0);  //Document type (DTD)
        }
        catch(DOMException& e)
        {

            BL_LOG_MSG(BL_FATAL,"Caught dom exception with message :<1>",XMLString::transcode(e.getMessage()))
            return NULL;
        }
```

edit 2:

Below is my  exact code still getting exception:

```
int main()
{

        DOMImplementation* p_DOMImplementation = NULL;
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
        p_DOMImplementation = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(convertStringToXmlCh("Core"));
        DOMDocument* pDomDocument=NULL;

        try
        {
               pDomDocument = p_DOMImplementation->createDocument(convertStringToXmlCh("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"),  //Root element namespace URI
                                                                   convertStringToXmlCh("soapenv:envelope"), // Root element name
                               NULL);  //Document type (DTD)
         }
         catch(DOMException& e)
         {
                cout <<"Caught xception:"<<e.getMessage();
                return NULL;
         }
         catch(...)
         {

                cout <<"Caught xception:";
                return NULL;
         }
         if(pDomDocument == NULL)
         {
                         return NULL;
                        cout<<"NULL returned";
         }

        DOMElement* pRootElement = pDomDocument->getDocumentElement();
        addAttributeToDomElementNS(pRootElement,"xmlns:typ","http://abcd.fg/V1/types");

        char* path = "/users/gen/app/mayank.xml";
        SerializeXmlWriter(pDomDocument,path);

        return 0;
}
```

Getting below exception: "Caught xception:invalid or illegal XML character"

Comment: Perhaps by default the implementation is not namespace aware. How do you create the implementation?

Comment: Try `getDOMImplementation(XMLString::transcode("Core XML")` to see whether that support namespaces. I don't think `Core` alone supports namespaces.

Comment: Or perhaps `getDOMImplementation(XMLString::transcode("Core 2.0")` is a way to ensure namespaces are supported as DOM Level 1.0 does not include namespace support.

Comment: @MartinHonnen- From where can I find valid values and check this?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR has the specs. I am however not familiar with Xerces C++ and how the DOM specs translate to C++.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Not working even after changing implementation. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Which version of Xerces C++ is that? Yesterday I grabbed the latest binary release I could find (3.1.1) and tried it with VS 2015 on Windows and some code following the provided sample CreateDOMDocument worked fine for me, even when trying to create namespaced SVG. There was no need to specify any version and code doing `DOMDocument* doc = impl->createDocument(X("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"),  X("svg:svg"), 0); ` and `doc->getDocumentElement()->appendChild(doc->createElementNS(X("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), X("svg:circle")));` worked fine. So I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: 3.1.1 Unix.. How was it implemented when it worked?

Comment: I have put the code I tried into an answer, to allow us to exchange the code. I realize it might not answer your question but putting some verbose C++ code into a comment does not make sense either.

Comment: Does it work now for you?

Comment: @MartinHonnen - I have added latest code and exception as part of Edit 2. Can you pease help?

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Thanks a lot for your help. Issue got resolved. I have added resolution in comment to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example based on the Xerces sample `CreateDOMDocument`, only creating elements in a namespace. The sample works fine for me on Window 10, compiled against a binary release of xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-windows-vc-10.0:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Includes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/OutOfMemoryException.hpp>

#if defined(XERCES_NEW_IOSTREAMS)
#include <iostream>
#else
#include <iostream.h>
#endif


XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_USE

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  This is a simple class that lets us do easy (though not terribly efficient)
//  trancoding of char* data to XMLCh data.
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class XStr
{
public:
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Constructors and Destructor
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    XStr(const char* const toTranscode)
    {
        // Call the private transcoding method
        fUnicodeForm = XMLString::transcode(toTranscode);
    }

    ~XStr()
    {
        XMLString::release(&fUnicodeForm);
    }


    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Getter methods
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    const XMLCh* unicodeForm() const
    {
        return fUnicodeForm;
    }

private:
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Private data members
    //
    //  fUnicodeForm
    //      This is the Unicode XMLCh format of the string.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    XMLCh*   fUnicodeForm;
};

#define X(str) XStr(str).unicodeForm()


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  main
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argC, char*[])
{
    // Initialize the XML4C2 system.
    try
    {
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
    }

    catch (const XMLException& toCatch)
    {
        char *pMsg = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());
        XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER cerr << "Error during Xerces-c Initialization.\n"
            << "  Exception message:"
            << pMsg;
        XMLString::release(&pMsg);
        return 1;
    }

    // Watch for special case help request
    int errorCode = 0;
    if (argC > 1)
    {
        XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER cout << "\nUsage:\n"
            "    CreateDOMDocument\n\n"
            "This program creates a new DOM document from scratch in memory.\n"
            "It then prints the count of elements in the tree.\n"
            << XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER endl;
        errorCode = 1;
    }
    if (errorCode) {
        XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
        return errorCode;
    }

    {
        //  Nest entire test in an inner block.


        DOMImplementation* impl = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(X("Core"));

        if (impl != NULL)
        {
            try
            {
                DOMDocument* doc = impl->createDocument(
                    X("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"),                    // root element namespace URI.
                    X("svg:svg"),         // root element name
                    0);                   // document type object (DTD).

                doc->getDocumentElement()->appendChild(doc->createElementNS(X("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), X("svg:circle")));

                //
                // Now count the number of elements in the above DOM tree.
                //

                const XMLSize_t elementCount = doc->getElementsByTagName(X("*"))->getLength();
                XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER cout << "The tree just created contains: " << elementCount
                    << " elements." << XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER endl;

                DOMImplementationLS* lsImpl = (DOMImplementationLS*)impl;
                DOMLSSerializer* ser = lsImpl->createLSSerializer();

                XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER wcout << ser->writeToString(doc);

                doc->release();
                ser->release();
            }
            catch (const OutOfMemoryException&)
            {
                XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER cerr << "OutOfMemoryException" << XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER endl;
                errorCode = 5;
            }
            catch (const DOMException& e)
            {
                XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER cerr << "DOMException code is:  " << e.code << XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER endl;
                errorCode = 2;
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER cerr << "An error occurred creating the document" << XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER endl;
                errorCode = 3;
            }
        }  // (inpl != NULL)
        else
        {
            XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER cerr << "Requested implementation is not supported" << XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER endl;
            errorCode = 4;
        }
    }

    XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
    return errorCode;
}
```

Output on Windows with VS 2015 is

```
The tree just created contains: 2 elements.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no" ?><svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><svg:circle/></svg:svg>
```

so that works fine and does not exhibit the problem you say you get with your snippets.

Comment: Issue got resolved. Issue was the function which I was using to convert from String to XMLCh* was wrong. I changed to one in above code and it worked.